# How do i persist google translate pages after clicking link?

Tags: google-translate

My website is http://himalayanherbs.net/ .

I'd like to know if i could persist the translated language after clicking links. Say For example.

I click russian from the lanuage translator dropdown. The page gets translated into Russian.

If I click a link then the page which opens, opens up in english again. This can be frustrating to the customer.

Is there a way by which once i click Russian the default language gets set to Russian so I don't have to re-click russian again.

*Russian was an example. (The langauge clicked could be anyone from the drop down )

Comment: hi there, you can try to use cookie, so it will auto select the dropdown without user interaction every user select the page they visit, you can see it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569927/change-google-translate-dropdown-programatically

Answer (score -1):

A much simpler alternative would just be to include the free [Google Translate widget](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools) on all your pages. That way visitors select the language they would like to view the site in and Google dynamically does the rest (and persists their selection throughout the site). You then don't need to worry about trying to create and keep updated dozens of different HTML files for every page, each with it's own set of internal links (which, frankly, sounds like a nightmare to maintain).

Comment: Yea i did use this tool. But the language did not persist. [link]( http://himalayanherbs.net/demo/ ) Please view the link. Its more understandable that way.

Comment: I know your concern, It didn't translate at page load but translate 3-4 seconds later. that is because the google translate widget is javascript based, that means once the DOM element has been loaded, it starts executing translations. The only way to get through it is to execute your own tranlsation logic in the server side. Then it won't jump when loading pages