# Change Google Translate dropdown programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a site I tried adding the Google Translate dropdown using the following code:

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en'
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}

<script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

When you select from the dropdown that the google script inserts, a Google Translate bar appears at the top of the page, and all text is translated in to the selected language.

However if I try and trigger the dropdown change using JavaScript, it doesn't work:

```
$('.goog-te-combo').val('fr')
```

'French' is selected from the dropdown, however Google Translate is not triggered.

Why o why does it not work? I've also tried:

```
$('.goog-te-combo').trigger('click')
$('.goog-te-combo').change()
```

UPDATE: FYI this is not my site. I was using the Chrome console to load jQuery and execute the jQuery methods.

Comment: After inspecting the DOM tree, the dropdown added by the Google script does not appear to be in an iframe.

Comment: If you add `<div id="google_translate_element"></div>` prior to loading the script so Google can populate it with [additional UI](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools), you get a `select` that isn't part of an `iframe`. Unfortunately, even calling the event triggers on these elements doesn't trigger the translation either (but the selected item does change).

Comment: Got the same problem : did you resolve it?

Comment: It solved by joeyend. See his comment

Answer (score 16):

You can have your dropdown trigger a page reload. You can either reload the page with `#googtrans(en|ja)` or `#googtrans/en/ja` appended to the URL, or set the googtrans cookie value to `/en/ja` (where ja is an example of the selected target language) before reloading.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is already an old topic, but I just wanna share the solution I came up with the issue on firing the google translate select element change event.

Add function that will use the dispatchEvent or fireEvent function:

```
function triggerHtmlEvent(element, eventName) {
var event;
if(document.createEvent) {
    event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
} else {
    event = document.createEventObject();
    event.eventType = eventName;
    element.fireEvent('on' + event.eventType, event);
} }
```

after setting the value, get the DOM object for select (using document.getElement...) and call the function above:

```
triggerHtmlEvent(selectObject, 'change');
```

Comment: Hey, I am really interested in this solution its exactly what I have been looking for for the last 3 days. Do you happen to have a working version for this, I think I am missing something around "after setting the value, get the DOM object for select (using document.getElement...)" Thanks for your help

Comment: I get the error: TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using fireEvent for production: "This is a proprietary Microsoft Internet Explorer alternative to the standard EventTarget.dispatchEvent()"  reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/fireEvent

Comment: it is a complete working version you have to trigger the event like this 
$('.goog-te-combo').val('de');
triggerHtmlEvent(document.getElementsByClassName('goog-te-combo')[0], 'change');

Answer (score 4):

//to get currently selected language

```
string language=Request.Cookies["googtrans"].Value
```

//to set desired language

```
 Response.Cookies["googtrans"].Value = Your language;
```

//eg: Response.Cookies["googtrans"].Value = "/en/hi";

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your code:

```
//to get currently selected language
string language=Request.Cookies["googtrans"].Value
//to set desired language
 Response.Cookies["googtrans"].Value = Your language;
//eg: Response.Cookies["googtrans"].Value = "/en/hi";
```

Answer (score 2):

In looking at your page it appears that jQuery isn't loaded, so you won't be able to use the `$()` function.

You need to add a reference to jQuery in your `<head></head>` section, such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then

```
$('.goog-te-combo').val('fr');
```

should work.

Comment: That would make sense if `$('.goog-te-combo').val('fr')` didn't do anything, but the OP says that it changes the dropdown.

Comment: I understand that, but I took a look at the page and tried running `$('.goog-te-combo').val('fr');` in the console and got the error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'val' of null`.  And searching the source turns up no references to `jQuery`. So either he's removed jQuery since this question was posted or it never worked (or perhaps it remembered 'fr' from a previous selection and the OP mistook that for it working).

Comment: I don't think the page belongs to the OP.  I believe they are trying to interact with the page from an external domain... hence the problem.

Comment: Ahh... if that's the case then yes, cross-site scripting will be the problem.  I interpreted the question as the site belonging to the OP.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. It's not my site. I loaded jQuery in the console and that's where I ran the jQuery functions. I am planning on implementing a similar solution on a site I am building.

Answer (score 1):

Having spent quite a lot of time trying to get this to work too, I implemented the jquery translation plugin and was able to achieve everything I wanted to do quite easily including automatic translate to browser language on page load and clickable language links, flags etc.

Details of the plugin and downloads are here http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/

Comment: Hey does this plugin still work? I spent a few hours trying it with no joy. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use I wrote here. The google translate set the change function using the select 'select.goog-te-combo', if u use only the class, the JS don't call the correct listener. 
@joeyend way work, because the function identify the real 'selector'.

```
var trans = jQuery('select.goog-te-combo');
trans.val('fr')
trans.change();
```